# How to run one script to another python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script that runs combination from a to z for two letters. i need to run the output of those combination to another script how can i achieve that? it has to run each combination and produce result and move on to next one.

```
# Get all permutations of length 2 
# and length 2 
perm = permutations([1, 2, 3], 2) 
# Print the obtained permutations 
for i in list(perm): 
    print i
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what your scripts look like?

Comment: import itertools      
d ={'1':['a','b'], '2':['c','d']}
for combo in itertools.product(*[d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys())]):
    print(''.join(combo))

Comment: i want the result of this combination to be run by another script one at a time

Comment: Use functions (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), modules (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and imports

Comment: i tried that i didn't do what i wanted. i wanted each one of the combination to run and display result before another combination runs and so on